# i2cdetect showing only one slave at a time

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

I want to use two [MCP23017-E/SP](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001952C.pdf) chips to extends the ports of a Raspberry PI 3. 
I'm using the `i2c-tools` on the Raspbian to confirm everything works. I've wired up both chips separately pinned them to two different addresses (0x20 and 0x24). With each connected separately I'm able to use them just fine, but when I use/power both at the same time I see very a strange behavior. It seems that only one of them is active at a time. Running `i2cdetect` shows varying results on every run:

```
# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: 20 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         
# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- 24 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Also `i2cset`/ `i2cget` would fail one time and succeed other times.

Colleges mentioned that the pull-up resistors might be required, but I assume that the RPi3 has 1k8 Ω resistors built in and I would not need additional ones.

The wiring is done like this, just with the Raspberry connections on `SDA1` and `SCL1` and Vdd on 3.3V.

[image: two port extenders on one Arduino]

How could I debug this further?

Comment: You should start by powering the MCP23017 circuit with 3.3V. The Raspberry Pi I²C port is 3.3V only. Or you have to insert a level shifter.

Comment: Sorry - indeed I power the MCP23017 with 3.3V - when I inserted the image I oversaw the 5V part.

Comment: Can you try adding decoupling capacitors across your VSS and VDD rails? That is probably the cause. If that works, I can add a brief explanation. Or I'm sure someone already posted a good explanation.

Comment: I threw in what I had laying around - I used the Ceramic 102 (1000pF) capacitors and indeed that solved it, thank you :)

Comment: Why is it voted down without comment? It wasn't obvious for me and I couldn't solve this with Google. Therefore this is imho a valid answer. Isn't it?

Comment: @pagid You mean to say "a valid question"? Anyway, some people are just tired seeng the same "LED without resistor", "Relay without flyback", "IC without decoupling caps", "5V signals to 3.3V controller" questions again and again every day.

Comment: Also, you're expected to provide a schematic, not a wiring diagram.

Comment: @Dmity  .... if that question is a regular one then you're supposed to mark the question as duplicate and reference other SE answers. Downvoting without leaving a comment is the same bad behaviour, as asking without doing research upfront. I did the research (as I described) but could find a working answer up until then.